# Warning: You are using Apple M1 chip and you have not specified container architecture, you might encounter issues while running act

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions, nektos-act

I'm trying to setup `nektos/act` locally so I can test my github workflows. When I run `act -l` I'm receving the follow working.

> ⚠ You are using Apple M1 chip and you have not specified container architecture, you might encounter issues while running act. If so, try running it with '--container-architecture linux/amd64'. ⚠

Do you know how can why and how I can get rid of this warning?

*Not sure if this is true, but it seems that I need to configure something in docker?*

Comment: "**Not sure if this is true""*, that you're using M1?

Comment: Did you run `act` with `--container-architecture linux/amd64`?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `linux/arm64` if you are running it on M1 chip?

Comment: @Azeem: Paweł is right, it should be `linux/arm64`.

Answer (score 2):

**Run it with linux/arm64 (fitting to your processor) to skip the warning:**

```
act --container-architecture linux/arm64
```

Though it is not necessary:
"If not specified, will use host default architecture. Requires Docker server API Version 1.41+. Ignored on earlier Docker server platforms."

Answer (score 0):

Just add `--container-architecture linux/amd64` and it should be fine.

```
act --container-architecture linux/amd64
```